# Can I reference an overloaded method using C# documentation tags?

Tags: c#, xml, comments

In this particular code sample I want to reference the second overloaded method (int n) from [C# documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax(v=VS.71).aspx) tags:

```
/// <summary>
/// The method to pass an integer to is <see cref="DoSomething">
/// </summary>

void DoSomething() {
}
void DoSomething(int n)  {
}
void DoSomething(string str) { 
}
```

But how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a cref to method overloads in a <seealso> tag in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419702/how-to-make-a-cref-to-method-overloads-in-a-seealso-tag-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ReSharper helps me complete `cref` attributes, it includes the argument types when there are overloads (i.e. `DoSomething(int)`).  I'm assuming that this is the valid way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

When Visual Studio generates the XML documentation file containing the comments for the associated assembly each documented member will be identified by a unique name. You can check the rules for this ID generation at:

[Processing the XML File (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx)

Of special interest would be the rule for methods with base type arguments, that says:

> For properties and methods, if there
>   are arguments to the method, the
>   argument list enclosed in parentheses
>   follows. If there are no arguments, no
>   parentheses are present. The arguments
>   are separated by commas. The encoding
>   of each argument follows directly how
>   it is encoded in a .NET Framework
>   signature:
>
> - Base types. Regular types (ELEMENT_TYPE_CLASS or
>     ELEMENT_TYPE_VALUETYPE) are
>     represented as the fully qualified
>     name of the type.
> - ...

In your case would result in a ID of (`M:YourNamespace.YourType.DoSomething(System.Int32)`), which could then be used in the `cref` attributes.