# XML Commenting -- How to seealso to the method overload page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, overloading, sandcastle, xml-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a cref to method overloads in a <seealso> tag in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419702/how-to-make-a-cref-to-method-overloads-in-a-seealso-tag-in-c)

How can I XML comment my code so that I point to something like this instead of each individual method? [ComputeHash Overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash.aspx)

```
/// <seealso cref="????"/>
public void Foo(String bar) { }

public void Foo(Int32 bar) { }

public void Foo(Double bar) { }
```

Basically, what do you type in the `cref` so that it references the method overload page similar to how the MSDN does?